# How to order posts by descending comment count on taxonomy page?

Tags: query-posts

This lists the posts in my custom taxonomy template page:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

How can I order those posts by comment count?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A friend helped me with a solution that I could place in my functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts' );

function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

    if ( is_tax( 'locations' ) && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) )
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'comment_count' );

    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

WP Query has a comment_count parameter since 2.9.

So:

```
query_posts(array('orderby' => 'comment_count', 'posts_per_page' => '10'));
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

Comment: FYI: You have curly quotes in your code sample.

Comment: I tried this, but it listed posts that had nothing to do with the particular custom taxonomy.

Comment: That was not really your question.